# du calculating whole directory size when we pipe the null input, how to stop it

Tags: linux, disk-usage, xargs

```
[emdfqmm@nfwne ncndnkln]$ ll -h | grep "Oct" | grep "2018" | xargs du -ch
5.0G    ./something
5.0G    .
5.0G    total

[emdfqmm@nfwne ncndnkln]$ ll -h | grep "Oct" | grep "2018" | wc -l
0
```

When it got null input its calculating the whole directory size how to stop it

Comment: I don't think any part of your command is doing what you want it to do.  This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Can you please redo your question to ask what your goal is and I'm sure someone can help you find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` has an option to not run if no input is  given:

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty
  If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run
  the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is
  no input.  This option is a GNU extension.
```

So use `xargs -r du -ch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with `-exec`:

```
month="Oct-2018";
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -newermt "01-$month -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$month +1 month -1 sec" -exec du -ch {} \;
```

Though, somehow I believe, you want `du -sh` instead of `du -ch`.

See

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)
- [UNIX / BASH: Listing files modified in specific month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289420/unix-bash-listing-files-modified-in-specific-month)